# Linux - Do a command repeatedly for a certain length of time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, centos

I know what the command watch -n does. I would like to do something like the following:

```
watch -n 5 "ls" //Do this for 30 minutes, then stop.
```

Essentially I want to repeat a command every 5 seconds, then stop after 30 minutes has passed. I'm missing the stop 30 minutes part. What command should I use to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use timeout:

```
timeout 1800 watch -n 5 "ls"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the timeout command, that is part of coreutils, something like:

```
 timeout 30m watch -n 5 "ls"
```

Comment: Note that there are multiple `timeout` versions.  If you don't have a recent GNU Coreutils, the syntax and options may be different.